# How to add tags when uploading a video using dailymotion python SDK?

Tags: python, dailymotion-api

I am trying to add tags when uploading videos to dailymotion.

Referring to [Dailymotion's guide](https://developer.dailymotion.com/guides/upload#samples), I write a code like followings.

```
d = dailymotion.Dailymotion()
d.set_grant_type('password', api_key=API_KEY, api_secret=API_SECRET,
    scope=['manage_videos'], info={'username': USERNAME, 'password': PASSWORD})
url = d.upload('./video.mp4')
d.post('/me/videos',
    {'url': url, 'title': 'MyTitle', 'published': 'true', 'channel': 'news', 'description':'MyDescription', 'tags': 'I,want,to,add,some,tags'})
```

I uploaded a video, title, channel and description successfully, but tags are empty.
Does anyone know how to add tags?

Answer (score 0):

I have tested your code and it seems working well. The video is created and tags are filled.

Can you provide a video id where you got this problem please?